# Windows 7 and partial backups with Windows Backup

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise:

```
systeminfo
OS Name:           Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:        6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
```

and trying to do a backup from the command line:

```
wbadmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:\\network\share -include:C:\temp
```

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083%28WS.10%29.aspx) for the **-include** switch states that I can include folders and/or files. However I'm presented with this message:

```
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2004 Microsoft Corp.

Retrieving volume information...
A partial backup of volumes is not supported on this version of Windows.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a 'server' edition of Windows for partial backup support, e.g. Windows Server 2008. It's not supported on Windows 7.

Comment: Hmmm.. but with the GUI I can make partial backups... no problems there...? But by googling, some users suggested what you're saying.